# Get the value of 'button.url'

Tags: django, wagtail

How does Wagtail get the value of '**url**' in '**page.button.url**'?

- home_page.html:

```
href="{{ page.button.url }}"
```

- models.py:

```
class HomePage(Page):
    button = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailcore.Page', 
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='+',
        help_text='Select an optional page to link to',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Like any other foreign key in Django: since `button` is a foreign key to a `wagtailcore.Page`, you'd look at whether `url` is a field, or a property on `Page` to see what it does.

Comment: There is no 'url' property in 'class Page(...)' in the file 'AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\wagtail\models\__init__.py'.

The only thing I found is this:

    def get_url(...):
    ...
    url = property(get_url)

Comment: Sure. That defines a property.